# SELECT result within select isn't reachable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query in a MySQL database:

```
SELECT o.*,
  (select IFNULL(sum(units_purchased),0) from member_purchase mp where 
    mp.offer_id = o.id and mp.is_deleted = 0) as sold_units
  FROM offer o 
  where o.partner_uid in ('941e08b6-f801-4656-8906-0a309b88c429') 
  and o.order_from < '2019-07-01' and o.order_to > '2019-07-10' and sold_units < o.servings and o.is_deleted = 0;
```

If I remove

> sold_units < o.servings

...t runs fine, but when I  leave it in it says:

> Unknown column 'sold_units' in where clause

Anyone knows what is causing this>?

Comment: You can't use a column alias in the WHERE on the same SELECT level

Comment: You will have to use `SELECT * FROM (<your_query>) AS alias WHERE alias.sold_units = ...`

Comment: Wrap select in outer select and then do the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Column aliases cannot be referenced in the `WHERE` clause.  That is the definition of the *SQL* language and is true in all databases.

The typical solutions are to use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.

MySQL has another work-around.  It allows the use of the `HAVING` clause in a non-aggregation query.  So, you can use:

```
select o.*,
       (select coalesce(sum(units_purchased), 0) 
        from member_purchase mp
        where mp.offer_id = o.id and
              mp.is_deleted = 0
       ) as sold_units
from offer o
where o.partner_uid in ('941e08b6-f801-4656-8906-0a309b88c429') and
      o.order_from < '2019-07-01' and 
      o.order_to > '2019-07-10' and
      o.is_deleted = 0
having sold_units < o.servings;
```

Comment: the having trick might also be possible in other databases as well by the way as ANSI/ISO SQL defined that `HAVING` can be used without `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

use subquery

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT o.*,
  (select IFNULL(sum(units_purchased),0) from member_purchase mp where 
    mp.offer_id = o.id and mp.is_deleted = 0) as sold_units
  FROM offer o 
  where o.partner_uid in ('941e08b6-f801-4656-8906-0a309b88c429') 
  and o.order_from < '2019-07-01' and o.order_to > '2019-07-10'
)A where sold_units < servings and is_deleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as per suggestion from @Raymond I ended up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT o.*,
(select IFNULL(sum(units_purchased),0) from member_purchase mp where mp.offer_id = o.id and mp.is_deleted = 0) as sold_units
FROM offer o where o.partner_uid in ('941e08b6-f801-4656-8906-0a309b88c429') and o.order_from < '2019-07-02 10:00:00' and o.order_to > '2019-07-02 10:00:00' and o.is_deleted = 0) as results where results.sold_units < results.servings;
```